# open guest network traffic monitor OS X

Tags: logging, wifi

I have a NETGEAR DGN2200 router and I have a primary wifi network for me to use with a security password and another open guest network with no password.
I have a log set up which sends me a report like this…

```
[DHCP IP: (192.168.0.2)] to MAC address xxx, Tuesday, Jun 05,2018 08:08:32

[DHCP IP: (192.168.0.3)] to MAC address yyy, Tuesday, Jun 05,2018 07:50:36

[DHCP IP: (192.168.0.3)] to MAC address zzz, Tuesday, Jun 05,2018 07:32:59
```

(xyz replaced MAC address by me)

which is quite meaningless to me and therefore less than useful.

What I want to see a log of is the url or ip address of the sites that are visited from anyone using my open guest network from the street outside to get idea if I should continue providing the internet access or not. I would also like to know how much data is being downloaded by the open guest network. I don't need any of their details, only what sites are visited.

The only thing I have come across that might do what I require is OpenDNS [1] but it seems to need all the info routed through their site?
What do you suggest I try? I prefer a free open source solution.

I have an iMac 10.11.6

[1] https://www.pcworld.com/article/3143456/networking/how-to-monitor-websites-visited-on-a-home-network.html